# Is there an a-frame event that fires after an entity is initialized?

Tags: aframe

I am looking for a way to detect when a new a-frames element has been added as a child of a given element(like "child-attached") but doesn't fire until the elements components have been initialized

alternatively, is there an event that is raised after an elements components have all been initialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `loaded` event will fire when all components initialized. This event doesn't bubble.  I would have a component that you attach to the dynamically added entities, and listen to `load` event. Better yet, set `dependencies` to wait for the exact component you need.

Related, the `componentinitialized` event will fire for each initialized component.